# How to protect nightly feature 'extended_key_value_attributes' behind a crate feature?

Tags: rust, rustdoc

I run code using stable and document it using nightly, mostly because of the automatic links.

I tried to include a long inner documentation by `#![doc = include_str!("doc.md")]` in the code, but only use it if using nightly, as it is unstable. The standard way to do it seems to be with an explicit feature.

I declared a `nightly` feature on my Cargo.toml, and tried:

```rust
#![cfg_attr(feature = "nightly", 
    feature(extended_key_value_attributes),
    doc = include_str!("doc.md"))]
```

which works as expected with `cargo +nightly doc --features nightly`, but is not supported by stable:

```
> cargo +stable build
[...]
error[E0658]: arbitrary expressions in key-value attributes are unstable
```

I suspect the `cfg_attr` has to parse all its arguments even if not using them, so the macro syntax within the `#[]`makes things more complicated.

How can I do this correctly?

Comment: *mostly because of the automatic links* — those are stable as of Rust 1.48.

Comment: Try moving the code that uses the feature into a separate file / module and add the `cfg` statement to the `mod`. Hopefully, that way the file isn't even parsed.

Comment: See also [How is it possible to keep Rust module documentation in separate Markdown files?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57421673/155423) for how to do the behavior you want even in stable.