# Is there a way to "do macro stuff" in an attribute without a procedural macro?

Tags: rust, rust-macros, rust-decl-macros

Specifically, I'm trying to put macro output into a doc comment. I was excited that this does exactly what I want:

```
/// foo
///
#[doc="bar\n\nbaz"]
///
/// quux
struct Dummy;
```

The next step would be to replace that string with my content. According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41945628/is-it-possible-to-emit-rust-attributes-from-within-macros), I can't write `#[doc=my_content!()]`, and attribute macros are procedural, so I need another crate for that, plus (I think) my content could be generated without the need for any procedural macro features.

Is there a way to do this with "conventional macros" in some way, or am I out of luck?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: starting with 1.54.0, [Attributes can invoke function-like macros](https://blog.rust-lang.org/2021/07/29/Rust-1.54.0.html), enabling the code proposed in the question. Original answer below :

---

The answer seems to be no.

Looking at the [grammar for attributes](https://doc.rust-lang.org/grammar.html#attributes), apart from parentheses, commas and equals signs, attributes can ultimately only contain literals. So on this level, there is no way Rust allows more here.

---

However, inverting the structure enables something like this, and the [`doc-comment`](https://docs.rs/doc-comment/0.3.1/doc_comment/) crate does this for doc comments. Instead of calling a macro from inside an attribute, use a macro to create an attribute; that macro is then not constrained to only taking literals*. The downside is, the item that the attribute should apply to must be part of the macro call. So this

```
#[doc=my_content!()]
struct Foo;
```

becomes this:

```
doc_comment!(
    my_content!(),
    struct Foo;
);
```

The definition of the macro is straight-forward:

```
#[macro_export]
macro_rules! doc_comment {
    ($x:expr, $($tt:tt)*) => {
        #[doc = $x]
        $($tt)*
    };
}
```

(omitted a branch of [the original macro](https://github.com/GuillaumeGomez/doc-comment/blob/master/src/lib.rs#L147) that is not part of the core pattern)

(thanks to jonas-schlevink for [pointing](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/61795#issuecomment-501657700) me to this)

---

*except for that last part (getting macro content into the attribute), the [linked question's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41945753/371191) already does exactly that.